# How to find 2 points on 2 lines (1 on each line) so that the distance between them is minimized?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Given that $L_1$ is the line in parametric form $x = s + 1, y = s − 2, z = 2s + 3$ and $L_2$ is the line in parametric form $x = -5t - 1, y = -7t - 2, z = t$.

How can I find the points $p_1$ on $L_1$ and $p_2$ on $L_2$ such that the distance between them is minimized?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A(1+s,-2+s,3+2s)$ and $B(-1-5t,-2-7t,t)$.

Thus, $$\vec{AB}(-2-5t-s,-7t-s,-3+t-2s).$$
Now, we have the following system.
$$(1,1,2)\vec{AB}=0$$ and
$$(-5,-7,1)\vec{AB}=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

$P(s+1,s-2,2 s+3);\;Q(-5 t-1,-7 t-2,t)$

$PQ=f(s,t)=\sqrt{(2 s-t+3)^2+(s+5 t+2)^2+(s+7 t)^2}=\sqrt{6 s^2+20 s t+16 s+75 t^2+14 t+13}$

The minimum for $PQ$ is when $f'_s=0;\;f'_t=0$ that is

$20 s+150 t+14=0\to 10 s+75 t+7=0\\12 s+20 t+16=0\to 3 s+5 t+4=0$

$s= -\dfrac{53}{35},t= \dfrac{19}{175}$

which lead to points

$P\left(-\dfrac{18}{35},-\dfrac{123}{35},-\dfrac{1}{35}\right),\;Q\left(-\dfrac{54}{35},-\dfrac{69}{25},\dfrac{19}{175}\right)$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=(1,1,2)$ and $u_0=(1,-2,3)$ while $v=(-5,-7,1)$ and $v_0=(-1,-2,0)$

The shortest distance between $u_0+su$ and $v_0+tv$ is in the direction of $u\times v$. The plane of vectors from $v$ in the direction of $u\times v$ is perpendicular to $(u\times v)\times v$. If $v_0$ and $u_0+su$ are in that plane, then
$$
(u_0+su-v_0)\cdot(u\times v)\times v=0
$$
Similarly,
$$
(v_0+tv-u_0)\cdot(u\times v)\times u=0
$$
Solving for $s$ and $t$ and plugging these back in give the points
$$
\underbrace{u_0+\frac{(v_0-u_0)\cdot(u\times v)\times v}{u\cdot(u\times v)\times v}u}_{\large u_1=\left(-\frac{18}{35},-\frac{123}{35},-\frac1{35}\right)}\quad\text{and}\quad\underbrace{v_0+\frac{(u_0-v_0)\cdot(u\times v)\times u}{v\cdot(u\times v)\times u}v}_{\large v_1=\left(-\frac{54}{35},-\frac{69}{25},\frac{19}{175}\right)}
$$
It is simple to check that $(u_1-v_1)\cdot u=(u_1-v_1)\cdot v=0$, so $u_1$ and $v_1$ are the points closest to each other on those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Put 
\begin{eqnarray*}
  f(s,t) &=& d(p_1,p_2) \\
   &=& \sqrt{(2+s+5t)^2+(s+7t)^2+(3+2s-t)^2} \\
   &=& \sqrt{75t^2+ 6s^2+13 + 16s+14t +20st} \\
  g(s,t) &=& 75t^2+ 6s^2+13 + 16s+14t +20st 
\end{eqnarray*}

$${\partial g\over \partial s} = 12s+20t+16 =0 $$
$${\partial g\over \partial t} = 75t+20s+14 =0 $$

Now solve this system and you are done.